# How to unlock new blocks and items?

Tags: super-mario-maker

What actions contribute to unlocking new blocks?
Is it based on how many blocks you put down in the level creator and if so, is it possible to just fill the screen with blocks until I have everything unlocked?

Comment: It would appear you receive new blocks at a [daily rate](http://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/how-to-unlock-all-tools-and-styles-in-super-mario-maker/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to spend 5 minutes in the level editor after receiving new items for it to tell you that your next shipment is on its way.

As of 1.01, it takes a certain amount of block placements after that before the game will tell you that your shipment arrived early.

It appears to count mass copy and paste segments in this set... about 5-6 screens worth of copy and pasting usually does the trick, but you may also have to use each new element at least once.

Comment: Side note: 1.01 was a day one patch.